# How do you manage multiple releases in multiple environments in continuous integration/delivery?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to wrap my head around this. Most CI/CD examples/projects have a single master that is always released, and have some variant of, e.g. git-flow, to have a develop branch. Once tagged, it goes to master.

Either way, `master` is always released to production.

But in the real world as I see it, there are human gates for release to production and other environments. What mechanism do you use to *manage* the deployment of different versions?

For example:

- v1.5 is the current production release
- v1.6 has passed all tests, artifacts are ready, it is tagged as valid, but business decides to deploy it only to staging, awaiting an opportune moment to deploy
- v1.5 is deployed to a demo environment
- v2.0 has also passed all tests, but is in UAT, subject to the customer being happy, as it is a major release

There could be many more such environments - production, staging, UAT, demo, demo2, etc.

What mechanism do you use to handle the tagging of a particular version for a particular environment, and the actual deployment thereof?

Answer (score 5):

Although there a probably a few ways to do it, I use the build pipeline plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin Along with the copy artifacts plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

With these, you can create individual jobs for each piece of your environment, and link them altogether.
So as in your example, the pipeline would look like:

Build -> Test and Deploy to UAT (2.0) -> deploy to staging(1.6) -> demo(1.5) -> prod (1.5)

Each piece represents a different build in jenkins. The idea behind continuous integration is you create the binaries once, and you carry it down the pipeline, only changing configuration pieces along the way. In a build job, the artifacts are created and then archived. In any jobs after, the artifact is picked up from the upstream job, some stuff is done, and then it get's re-archived for the next downstream job. So the deploy to staging would go to the Test and Deploy to Uat job to get its binary. The entire concept of Continuous Delivery boils down to the the build pipeline. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery (and yes I did just cite wikipedia).

As for tagging individual binaries for specific environments, that is by definition, not continuous integration. A binary is suppose to be created in a way that it can easily be propagated from one environment to the next. So unfortunately, individual builds for specific environments can never be continuous delivery. You can use jenkins as a CI server all you want, but if your process does not match, you will never achieve true continuous integration.

Braching, merging and checkins always seems to be a touchy subject when it comes to Continuous Integration, so I won't go into it much. But a lot of people share the idea that : "If different members of the team are working on separate branches, then by definition, they not participating in continuous integration process." http://eugenedvorkin.com/continuous-integration-strategies-for-branching-and-merging/

*EDIT*
For Flagging specific builds, it sounds like your looking to take use of this feature : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint ... Which gets the job done effectively, giving you the entire life of any individual artifact. A bit more complex solution would be artifactory, which is essentially artifact source control.

I explained the concept of the deployment process above, and without information on your specific environment it is hard to go much further. But for me, for java applications deployed to tomcat containers, the deploy plugin works great https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

You shouldn't have to worry about selection of which artifact to deploy. The pipeline should be setup to always deploy the latest artifact that was archived in its corresponding upstream job.

Comment: Hey @Cole9350 thanks for the detailed answer. So I am good on the pipeline, and the end result is not specific binaries for each environment. Instead I will have, e.g. 3 different artifacts: v2.0, v1.6, v1.5. What mechanism to I use to actually flag and deploy the different artifacts to each environment? I am 100% on with the same artifact can be used in either; it is the flagging/selection/deployment to the environment process I am struggling with

Comment: OK, so to add for the specific environment: EC2 instances, highly disposable. An instance pops up, grabs the latest artifact (Docker image to keep it simple), and away it runs. But each one needs to know which one to grab. I prefer not to put too much logic on the app server, but some form of, "hey, I am env X, so I ask and am told to get artifact version Y, and here it is" is ideal

Comment: Control the instances from inside jenkins, labeling each one a specific instance, Dev, UAT, Demo ect. Link them altogether, so build points to dev, dev points to Uat ect. This is the build pipeline, I cannot put it any differently. Each one doesn't know which war they're getting, it just knows to take whatever got successfully through the last stage in the pipeline

Comment: Control them from inside jenkins? Push instead of pull? Interesting. I need to think that one through... because I don't fully get it...

Comment: Yes, for builds you pull, for deployments you push. Because of the statement in your question "But in the real world as I see it, there are human gates for release to production and other environments." We push because we are waiting for the gatekeeper to say it is ok to. Unless you wanna walk up to your project manager every hour and ask him if its ok to deploy http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContinuousDelivery.html

Comment: Tempting to wake him, tempting.... :-) But it is more of a functionality rather than stability question. The business gets to decide when v2.0 is good for customers; technology gets to decide when it is stable for customers.

Comment: Yes, which is why the build pipeline plugin is so useful, it allows you to specify manual steps (waiting approval), as well as automatic steps (deploy to test). There should be some type of ordering to your approval and deployment process. You just have to set that order up like a pipeline. I highly recommend this book http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003YMNVC0/

Comment: The funny thing is, by chance, I re-read the book not a few weeks ago! It does a really good job of addressing that. But I didn't find anything about managing multiple environments simultaneously, essentially server X gets version A, server Y gets version C, etc.

Comment: The reason why you didn't find anything about what your describing, is because it is not continuous integration. In CI, all servers get the same version. Different versions get propagated further down the pipeline than others, which creates the scenario your referring to, but no instance has knowledge of exactly what war to take, just where to take it from. This is the concept of promotions, which you reffered to as "pushing", sort of. If you have the concepts down, move onto how to apply them : http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide Chapter 10.7, pg 285 (Free download).

Comment: I don't get it? Why would multiple environments with different versions not qualify as CI?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Docker can help you out with this issue. It is able to deploy images of projects to a specific environment. If that environment has a docker client or a docker deamon you are able to request specific information about that environment and the project (to be) deployed on it.

Jenkins can still play a huge part in your pipeline for the integration part and you could let docker do the delivery part.

Docker: https://www.docker.com

Docker plugin for jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin

Docker also has support for windows machines and .NET.

Comment: Actually, it was a conversion to Docker images that prompted the question. Changing to better technology often prompts a reassessment of current state (a.k.a. "what the hell were we doing *that* for???"). :-)

Comment: Yes i can see the problem. At the moment i am writing my thesis about continious delivery to multiple environments and the goal is to find a solution for problems similar to yours. In june I should have my conclusions.

Comment: I very much would like to see it, when you are done.

Comment: If you can send my your email or other way to contact you, i will send the thesis when it is finished.

Comment: All of my contact info is on my company Contact page. http://blog.atomicinc.com/contact/ Good luck... and thanks!